# regular expression to find exact match

Tags: regex, typescript

In a comma separated string I am looking for exact match of a number.

```
4,44,24 - expected 4,
44,4,24 - expected 4,
4 - expected 4
```

I am looking for 4 and not 44 and 24.

I have tried `/\b4,/g`  to have the word boundary.

```
4,44,24  - Matches 
44,4,24 - Matches
4 - fails
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use 2 word boundaries `\b4\b` as `\b4,` matches a mandatory comma.

Answer (score 1):

While you could use `\b4\b`, which would assert that a non-word-character e.g. `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` is to the right or left of `4`. You could even be more specific than that in your exact example. Assuming your actual data does not include  `- expected 4` you could write

```
(?<=^|,)4(?=$|,)
```

(See https://regex101.com/r/rPUIvt/latest)

asserting that the 4 will either be preceded by a start of line (`^`) or `,` and is followed by end-of-line (`$`) or `,`.